# If we write $\ln(x):=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$, can we show that the natural logarithm tells us the power $e$ must be raised to in order to get $x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, definition

The way I was first introduced to the logarithm was that $\log_ab$ means 'the power you need to raise $a$ by in order to get $b$'. Additionally, $a$ and $b$ must be greater than $0$. If I tried to formalise this notion, then I would probably come up with something like

$$
\log_ab := n \text{ such that } a^n=b, \text{ where } a,b>0
$$

However, I have found that many logarithms are instead defined using integrals. In particular, the natural logarithm is often defined as

$$
\ln(x):= \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt
$$

Is there a way of showing that this definition still satisfies my intuitive conception of what a logarithm is? In other words, can we show that

$$
\ln(x):= \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt \implies \ln(x)=n \text{ such that } e^n=x, \text{ where } x>0
$$

Even better would be to show that

$$
\ln(x)= \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt \iff \ln(x)=n \text{ such that } e^n=x, \text{ where } x>0
$$

Where you use either the LHS or the RHS as the starting point for your definition.

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by $e$, or $e^x$. There are several equivalent ways to define exp. (I say ways to define $exp$ because with your definition, if you show your $\ln$ is increasing, then exp is "the inverse of $ln$". Here you can show using properties of the integral that $\ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b$, $\ln(a^b) = b \ln a$, $ln(1/a) = -\ln a$, etc. From this it follows that $\ln a^x / \ln a = x$, ie $\ln$ inverts exponentiating. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Right, so we can show that $\ln(x)$ satisfies some of the essential properties of logarithms, one of them being $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$. Is this a necessary or a sufficient condition for a logarithm?

Comment: Good question! Certainly the logarithm must have this property, and so do any multiples of it (which you can think of as logarithms in different bases). I think that any function on the positive with this property that is continuous at any point is necessarily a multiple of the logarithm. However, by taking a basis of $\Bbb R$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, we can manufacture a discontinuous solution. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) - if $f$ satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$, then let $g(x) = f(\ln x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the functions $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ are strange in that they can be *defined* in a variety of ways, all of which are equivalent. You can, for example, define $\exp(x)$ to be either of the following:
$$
\exp(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)^{nx}, \quad \textrm{or} \quad  \exp(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$
Yet another definition gives $\exp(x)$ as the unique function $f(x)$ with the property that $f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0) = 1$ (and yes, $\exp(x)$ is the *only* function with this property). In each of these instances, it is a different (but not terribly difficult) matter to show that $\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$ from these definitions. So really what you want to do is prove that using one of these definitions, $\exp(\ln(x)) = x$ and $\ln(\exp(x)) = x$ for $x > 0$.

Let's suppose we take the approach that $\exp(x) = \exp'(x)$ and $\exp(0) = 1$, for whatever this function $\exp(x)$ actually is, and $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1 t \,dt$. Let $g(x) = \ln(\exp(x))$. Then $g(0) = 0$, and since $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(x) = \frac 1 x$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
g'(x) = \frac{\exp'(x)}{\exp(x)} = \frac{\exp(x)}{\exp(x)} = 1
$$
from which we can deduce that $g(x) = x$. A similar strategy can be used to show $\exp(\ln(x)) = x$, so $\exp$ and $\ln$ are function inverses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: in this approach, $\mathrm e$ is the number such that
$$\ln \mathrm e=\int_1^{\mathrm e}\frac{\mathrm d t}{t}=1.$$

Therefore,
$$\mathrm e^{y}=x\iff y\ln\mathrm e=y=\ln x. $$

Comment: Thank you for responding. In order to make this solution rigorous, do we have to show that the natural logarithm, when defined as an integral, satisfies the power rule for logarithms? Or is this solution already rigorous?

Comment: If you take for granted that $\log(xy)=\log x+\log y$, the power rule rule for integer exponents is valid, then you can deduce it for rational exponents, and taking into account the continuity of the logarithm, you get it for real exponents.

Comment: Now I think about it, if $\exp(y)=x$, then $\log(\exp(y))=y=\log(x)$, so this approach is fairly direct.

Comment: (It's just too bad that it took me over a year to think of this!)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function $\ln$ defined in the question is one-to-one.

Assume that $e$ is such that $e^x$ is the unique function $y$ that satisfies $y’=y,y(0)=1$. Then the question boils down to showing that the following function $y=f(x)$ equals $x$:

**Proposition**. If $y=f(x)=e^{\int_1^x 1/t~dt},f(1)=1$, then $f(x)=x.$

Proof. Taking derivatives, one has $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac yx$$ $$\Rightarrow \frac 1 y~dy=\frac 1 x~dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \ln y=\ln x,~{\rm since~}f(1)=1$$
$$\Rightarrow y=x,$$ since $\ln$ is one-to-one.