# Can we define $\ln(x)$ as a solution of $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))=\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

Can we define $\ln(x)$ as the solution of the differential equation $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))=\frac{1}{x}$$ such that $\ln(1)=0$?

Comment: Yep, although you need to say something about existence and uniqueness.

Comment: Simpler: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726930/if-we-write-lnx-int-1x-frac1tdt-can-we-show-that-the-natural-lo)

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you don't know anything about power series, that's probably the easiest way of defining it.

Comment: Yes of course you can. Simply ${f(x)=\ln(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt}$. As @QiaochuYuan has said though - you must prove existence and uniqueness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, I know another interesting way to define the logarithm map.

We fix $\mathbb{R}^+$ with the following operations:

$a+b:=ab$

$a\cdot b:=b^a$

It is easy to check $1$ is the neutral element with respect the sum and this object is a real vector space of dimension $1$.

In fact an isomorphism is the linear map

$exp : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+$

The element of a  base will be $\{e\}$ and we define the logarithm as the element of the dual base of $\{e\}$ in $(\mathbb{R}^+)^*$, i.e. that map $f: \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy

$f(e)=1$

$f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$

$f(b^a)=af(b)$

This corresponds exactly to the logarithm because

$f(a)=f(e^{log(a)})=f(log(a)\cdot e)=log(a)f(e)=log(a)$

In general the map $log_a(x)$ can be defined as the element of the dual base $\{a\}$ of $(\mathbb{R}^+)^*$

Comment: We can also find the morphism relation $f(ab)=f(a)+f(b)$ using changes of variable from the integral definition $\ln(x)=\int_1^x dt/t$. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3299124/399263.

Comment: @zwim Yes, your answer is exactly what I was saying. In your case the change of variables $t=e^x$ is exactly the bijection that permit us to fix on $R^+$ the operations of $R$ such that the elements of the dual space corresponds to the logarithm maps.